# Showing custom popup in safari if app is not installed

Tags: iphone, url-scheme, custom-url

I have written code in iOS for launching my app from a custom url in safari and it all works well as long as my app is installed. But if it is not installed then safari shows a popup saying it cannot open the page because the address is invalid. However, my stop page still opens up in the background prompting the user to app's link on app store.

My question is, how do i change this popup to show a custom message instead, a message that can relate to the stop page im displaying.